# Add column to table based on overall average of another column

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns

I have a table with providers, costs and number of items

I want to know what the cost would be for each provider if their price was at this average price

So I want the table to look something like this

Provider /  Cost  /  Items  /  Average cost per item  /  Cost at average price

1...........5........4.........3.125.....................12.5

2...........10.......5.........3.125.....................15.625

3...........20.......3.........3.125.....................9.375

4...........15.......4.........3.125.....................12.5

Totals......50.......16

What's the best way to do this? I have created a measure that gives the correct average cost of all providers but can't seem to add this to a table so that I can calculate the difference. I've tried looking here and elsewhere but can't find the solution. It can't be that rare but seems quite hard!

Any help much appreciated